# SAAS Architecture with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, soa, saas

I'm planning the basic architecture for a new software that will need to be modular.
I'm trying to define a multitenancy application to have a single instance running for all the users.

What I need is the possibility to scale when and where needed, so I don't like the idea to spawn multiple applications (monolitical architectured)  behind a load balancer when it could be a single part of the computation that needs more resources.

So I'm thinking about a Service Oriented Architecture, it would have the rails application as web client and other services, that could be virtually written in any language and accessed via APIs by the rails application.

I'd also like to have this APIs open to users to integrate with their existing software and easily extend these services.

I've some specific question:

- would it be a good idea to have this kind of architecture for a new startup (1-5 employees)?
- using APIs i don't need to use any RPC since the API request itself is an RPC, am I right on this concept?
- what would be a nice standard for the APIs (REST only defines HOW to access resources)?
- what could be, pratically, the best (= a good) way to expose those APIs to customers? Via the Web Rails application? Directly via a proxy that makes them all available under the same domain? APIs would be accessible in a RESTful way so via HTTP requests.
- with this kind of architecture would it be less expensive to have VPS's, Cloud, or dedicated servers? I like clouds because of their failure-tollerant nature, it would free us from worry about data persistence and backups (including the fact that we want to build an architecture almost 100% available).
- Any other suggestion or point of view, and any simply start point to think about this would be very appreciated.

I know very well Python, C/C++, JS, Perl, other pl and I started recently with Ruby/Rails. I'm choosing this last one because it seems to me that this community is strongly oriented in building services and what I mind (before that extreme performances) is the ability to learn asap and have someone to share experience with and to learn from, also with pratical examples (I know it's about an architecture, not PL that implements it, but I think it would be more easy to get it wrong in an immature environment that is still working with web1 or web2.0 style in mind).

P.S. I also need to write the basic architecture design, do you have any template where I can start from? I do need to share it with my team and other very-expert pros, I'd like to have it complete and easy to understand.

Hope to read some good suggestions here guys!

Thanks,
Alex.

Comment: Just gone through http://www.slideshare.net/ihower/distributed-ruby-and-rails. Starting from the slide #90 it answers some question.

Answer (score 1):

### Architecture

Here is an example stack that would I think mostly do what you're looking to accomplish:

**Cluster**

- One or more app servers
- One or more database servers
- Zero or more job servers

**Instances**

- [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) for configuration
- Unicorn or Passenger
- Nginx

**Application**

- Ruby on Rails
- Check out [Grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape) for simple APIs

### More Specific Answers

- > would it be a good idea to have this kind of architecture for a new startup (1-5 employees)?

  If done correctly, this approach can be very stable and robust. What you don't want to do it get into a situation where you are spending all your time managing your servers. You want to get it up, be able to deal with problem instances quickly, and work on making your application do stuff. If you do it right, creating instances can be simple and totally automated.
- > using APIs i don't need to use any RPC since the API request itself is an RPC, am I right on this concept?

  Yes.
- > what would be a nice standard for the APIs (REST only defines HOW to access resources)?

  Here we'd need a bit more clarification on how you need to use [RESTful design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Concept) to accomplish specific goals.
- > what could be, pratically, the best (= a good) way to expose those APIs to customers? Via the Web Rails application? Directly via a proxy that makes them all available under the same domain? APIs would be accessible in a RESTful way so via HTTP requests.

  A domain (or subdomain) should be accessible via HTTP and RESTful software design. It might return JSON or something else. It's all up to you.
- > with this kind of architecture would it be less expensive to have VPS's, Cloud, or dedicated servers? I like clouds because of their failure-tollerant nature, it would free us from worry about data persistence and backups (including the fact that we want to build an architecture almost 100% available).

  You get what you pay for. I'd recommend cloud servers. Check out Heroku to get started, or Rackspace if you are prepared to "roll your own." Or Engine Yard.
- > Any other suggestion or point of view, and any simply start point to think about this would be very appreciated.

  I would try creating a test API using something like a free Heroku account.